# Control logging output from third-party libraries used in a gradle plugin

Tags: java, logging, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle plugin that uses a library. The library uses archaius, which ends up logging some information using sl4j.

When I execute a task from my plugin, it ends up using this library, which then ends up using archaius. This means I start seeing all of these log messages that come from archaius. Is there any way to turn this off?

Things I have tried:

- Setting the log level from the plugin's apply method to `LIFECYCLE`/`QUIET`.
- Adding a `logging.properties` file to the plugin's `src/main/resources` with `com.netflix.level = QUIET`.

Neither of the above worked. Is there a way to disable these log messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Unfortunately it depends on internal classes in gradle, but I couldn't figure out any other way:

```
void apply(Project project) {
    OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext context = (OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext)  LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    context.reset()
    context.setOutputEventListener(new StfuLogger())
}


class StfuLogger implements OutputEventListener {
    @Override
    void onOutput(OutputEvent event) {
        LogEvent logEvent = (LogEvent) event
        if(!logEvent.category.contains("com.netflix")) {
            println(logEvent.message)
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to get the logger factory implementation that gradle uses, reset it, and then supply a new output-event listener. Doing it with `project.gradle.useLogger(new StfuLogger())` doesn't work.